# execute a shell script in jenkin using a local user

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Right now, whenever I run my shell script in Jenkins it runs the script as root.
I want to execute the script as a local user on slave.

My shell script

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo su - <username> 
echo "$USER"
```

This still gives root as user. How can I change the user is all the commands that I run in the shell script? Why did it show root user since I have already changed the user to a different user.

Thanks I advance.

Comment: What you are doing is certainly not making su run the echo command. It will attempt to run sudo su, then, when it's done, it will run echo. I think you provide what you run to su with -c, so you should try: `su - username -c 'echo $USER'`, and if it's starting to run as root, there is no point in using sudo.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It certainly did work for me. How can I ensure that all the commands that I am running in shell script are run as the same user(not as root)?

Comment: I guess the best thing you can do is set it up as a shell script and call that script with su. If that's not possible, you can have a long -c argument; `-c 'command1; command2; command3; etc'`..... but that is lacking elegance, if you ask me.

Comment: maybe configure `JENKINS_USER` in `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins-slave` ?